# zeus test_helper with rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, zeus

How can I modify my zeus.json file to run rspec tests in an engine I am developing alongside my application?

My Rails app looks something like this:

```
/config
/engines
  /engine <-- this is the engine I'm developing inside the parent app
    /spec <-- here are the rspec tests
/custom_plan.rb
/zeus.json
```

Normally, I `cd` into *engines/engine* and run `rspec` to run the engine tests (it has a dummy app it runs against).

Running `zeus init` in the top directory creates *zeus.json* and *custom_plan.rb*:

```
{
  "command": "ruby -rubygems -r./custom_plan -eZeus.go",

  "plan": {
    "boot": {
      "default_bundle": {
        "development_environment": {
          "prerake": {"rake": []},
          "runner": ["r"],
          "console": ["c"],
          "server": ["s"],
          "generate": ["g"],
          "destroy": ["d"],
          "dbconsole": []
        },
        "test_environment": {
          "test_helper": {"test": ["rspec", "testrb"]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

require 'zeus/rails'

class CustomPlan < Zeus::Rails

  # def my_custom_command
  #  # see https://github.com/burke/zeus/blob/master/docs/ruby/modifying.md
  # end

end

Zeus.plan = CustomPlan.new
```

Then when I run `zeus start` the test_helper start-up fails with

```
cannot load such file -- test_helper (LoadError)
```

My guess is because my specs are currently in *engines/engine/spec* and there is no "spec" folder in the parent app. I'd like to be able to update my custom_plan to run those tests instead. In lieu of that, I'd like to be able to create a separate plan and zeus.json inside the engine, but when I `cd` into engines/engine and run zeus init, it still creates the config files at the root of the application, so I'm not sure how to get zeus "into" my engine.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the path for test_helper. It is a method in the zeus gem: https://github.com/burke/zeus/blob/master/rubygem/lib/zeus/rails.rb#L185

I just had the same error for upgrading to rspec 3 and couldnt find any documentation for using zeus with rspec 3, so I set zeus.json:

```
{
  "command": "ruby -rubygems -r./custom_plan -eZeus.go",

  "plan": {
    "boot": {
      "default_bundle": {
        "development_environment": {
          "prerake": {"rake": []},
          "runner": ["r"],
          "console": ["c"],
          "server": ["s"],
          "generate": ["g"],
          "destroy": ["d"],
          "dbconsole": []
        },
        "test_environment": {
          "test_helper": {"spec": ["rspec"]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and custom_plan.rb

```
require 'zeus/rails'

class CustomPlan < Zeus::Rails

  def spec(argv=ARGV)
    RSpec::Core::Runner.disable_autorun!
    exit RSpec::Core::Runner.run(argv)
  end
end

# set rails_helper for rspec 3
ENV['RAILS_TEST_HELPER'] = 'rails_helper'
Zeus.plan = CustomPlan.new
```

So you could try setting `ENV['RAILS_TEST_HELPER']` to the path to your test_helper file.